# Why do I need the subexpression operator in this example?

Tags: powershell, substitution

A textbook example says

```
trap {"trapped : $($error[0])"; break}
```

in PowerShell. Why do I need the subexpression operator `$( )`? As a beginner I would see

```
trap {"trapped : $error[0]"; break}
```

enough as PowerShell does variable substitution in strings with double quotes.

Of course the latter does not work. Why?

Comment: Parsing rules. Let `$x` be `"banana"`, then `"$x[0]"` is `"banana[0]`", and not the first element of `$x` if it happens to contain an array. *Variable* substitution is not *expression* substitution.

Comment: I think this is an _answer_ and not just a _comment_.

Comment: I see your clever jab and appreciate it, though not enough to turn your thought into reality. Feel free to do so yourself, if you want.

Comment: I did, please upvote if you like it.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of an expandable string (one with outer double quotes or that has been converted to string), variable names are substituted with their values. This process ignores indexing (`$var[0]`) and member access (`$var.property`) because `.` and `[` are not allowed in variable names<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
# Example 1
$var = 'first','second'
$var[1] # retrieves element 1 correctly
second
"$var[1]" # converts $var into a string and then outputs [1] literally
first second[1]

# Example 2
$var = [pscustomobject]@{prop = 'value'}
$var.prop # outputs value as expected
"$var.prop" # converts $var to string and then outputs .prop literally
@{prop=value}.prop
```

The double quoted strings do evaluate expressions but the parser has to be told what the expression encompasses. Enter the subexpression operator `$()`. Code inside of the `()` is treated as an expression. Now the expression can be identified, evaluated, and have its result inserted into the string.

```
$var = [pscustomobject]@{prop = 'value'}
"$($var.prop)" # outputs value
value
```

See [About_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6) for additional information.

---

<sup>[1]: Special characters can be used in variable names. This is allowed in the case of syntax `${variableName}`. This special syntax is substituted correctly in double quoted strings.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

*Variable* substitution looks ahead only till the end of the variable name: $error.

One needs *expression* substitution to access the zeroth element of this variable, that's why there is this surrounding `$( )`.